# What am I doing wrong with this mule -jersey flow?

Tags: java, jersey, mule, mule-component

I'm trying to create a simple mule flow that extracts the header and passes the `user-agent` to a REST component that returns a status code based on the extracted user agent.

Here's my mule flow

```
  <flow name="restflowFlow1" doc:name="restflowFlow1">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="9595" path="rest" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
            <component class="com.test.RestClass"/>
        </jersey:resources>
    </flow>
```

And here is the corresponding class

```
@Path("restClass")
public class RestClass implements Callable {

    public Response getExample(String toBeValidated)
    {

        if(toBeValidated.contains("Apple"))
        {
            return Response.status(Status.OK).entity("hello " + toBeValidated).build();
        }
        return Response.status(Status.UNAUTHORIZED).entity("hello " + toBeValidated).build();
    }

    @Override
    public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
        String requiredHeader= eventContext.getMessage().getProperty("user-agent", PropertyScope.INBOUND);

        return getExample(requiredHeader);
    }
}
```

When I try to run the above flow I get the following error:

```
ERROR 2014-11-21 13:49:47,909 [[muletestproject].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to invoke JerseyResourcesComponent{restflowFlow1.component.418586223}. Component that caused exception is: JerseyResourcesComponent{restflowFlow1.component.418586223}. Message payload is of type: String
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. String index out of range: -1 (java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException)
  java.lang.String:1875 (null)
2. Failed to invoke JerseyResourcesComponent{restflowFlow1.component.418586223}. Component that caused exception is: JerseyResourcesComponent{restflowFlow1.component.418586223}. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.component.ComponentException)
  org.mule.component.AbstractComponent:144 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/component/ComponentException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1875)
```

P.S. Im quite new to mule. So I'm open to any other elegant approaches as well.

Answer (score 0):

To implement callable doenst make much sense for Jerse, you should use JAX-RS annotations, i.e:

```
package org.mule.transport.jersey;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

@Path("/helloworld")
public class HelloWorldResource {

    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @Path("/{name}")
    public String sayHelloWithUri(@PathParam("name") String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }
}
```

As stated [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Jersey+Module+Reference).

Comment: Why @Context HttpServletRequest returns null?

Comment: You are not running within a Servet server. There are ways to embed a servet server within Mule but it might be an overkill in many use cases. Could you please share the reason you need it?

Comment: I want to expose a jersey rest service and i should be able to get request information using @Context HttpServletRequest. Note In my case i am using servlet connector rather than http connector and i am hosting service in Tomcat server

Answer (score 0):

Implementing Callable in a java component gives it a feature to get invoked from your flow xml. In your case there is no need for Callable just annotate your service class with JAX-RS annotations so that jersey can publish the public methods in your class. When you post a request with the address resembling the path of your service class, jersey will automatically invoke the corresponding method.

```
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

@Path("restClass")
public class RestClass {
public Response getExample(@QueryParam("param1") String param1) {
     return Response.status(Status.OK).entity("hello " + param1).build();
  }
}
```

This should work for you.